# How to set and get various CalendarEvent values using GAS

Tags: google-apps-script, calendar

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event contains various methods for get / set a number of CalendarEvent data. But some that are available while using the Calendar web Ui are missing.

What about **Event colour** and **Attachment** ?

How can I use these from code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was not possible from Google-Apps-Script until recently.

It has been the subject of an [enhancement request](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=625) I posted a while ago.

but the [new enhanced calendar API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/calendar) offers the possibility of color coding the events. (nothing about attachments)

On the other hand, you can also use [Romain Vialard's library](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/new-connectors-to-google-services/calendar) that makes it much simpler to use. I developed a [spreadsheet example](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/new-connectors-to-google-services/calendar/calendar_edit_example) (published on his site) that makes use of all the available features.

### Edit following your comment :

here is an example taken from Google ref documentation :

```
function createEvent() {
  var calendarId = 'primary';
  var start = new Date(new Date().setHours(16));
  var end = new Date(new Date().setHours(22));
  var event = {
    summary: 'Lunch Meeting',
    location: 'The Deli',
    description: 'To discuss our plans for the presentation next week.',
    start: {
      dateTime: start.toISOString()
    },
    end: {
      dateTime: end.toISOString()
    },
    attendees: [
      {email: 'alice@example.com'},
      {email: 'bob@example.com'}
    ],
    // Red background. Use Calendar.Colors.get() for the full list.
    colorId: 11
  };
  event = Calendar.Events.insert(event, calendarId);
  Logger.log('Event ID: ' + event.getId());
}
```

It creates a "red" event in your calendar. You must enable the API before being able to run it : use the link in script editor/ressources as illustrated below and the next link they suggest.
[image]

**Once the service is active** you get all the new methods in the autocomplete ;-) nice !!

[image]

Comment: Nice calender applications. But I don't need that advanced apps (now). I Looked at https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/calendar#reference and the listCalendars() function does work. But still I don't get it really. Would you be so kind to write a few lines of code showing how to create an event and change the color of it. Thanks in advance